# Trying install a ppa package on Debian

Tags: debian

after running this code `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/sierrabreeze`in my bash using the debian 10 buster. the following error message appears right after trying `sudo apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                                                      
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease                                              
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                             
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                         
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thopiekar/sierrabreeze/ubuntu focal InRelease [15.4 kB]
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thopiekar/sierrabreeze/ubuntu focal InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D51DB14E9FFECCF3
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/thopiekar/sierrabreeze/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D51DB14E9FFECCF3
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/thopiekar/sierrabreeze/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

**Edit**

`sudo apt install sierrabreeze`:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sierrabreeze : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.28-10 is to be installed
                Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2) but 5.11.3+dfsg1-1+deb10u3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

any help to solve this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the gpg key manually:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys D51DB14E9FFECCF3
```

Also you need to edit the `thopiekar-ubuntu-sierrabreeze-focal.list` file.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/thopiekar-ubuntu-sierrabreeze-focal.list
```

Change `focal` to `bionic`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thopiekar/sierrabreeze/ubuntu bionic main
```

The run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sierrabreeze
```

Comment: Thank you so much @GAD3R! now i can do update normality.
But I still couldn't finish the installation.

Comment: Output
```sudo apt install sierrabreeze```

Comment: @Fgregorio1 welcome, your `/etc/apt/sources.list` contain some unstable repository. Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` [as described here](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list) then run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.